# While loop with Scanner

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch

why isn't this code working as expected?

```
public class FinalTest {
  public static void main (String [] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int k = 0;

    boolean askForInput = true;

    while ( askForInput ) {
      System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
      try {
        k = in.nextInt();
        askForInput = false;
      } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("ERR: Not an integer!!");
      }
    }

  }
}
```

`nextInt()` tries to scan the input as an int, and if it is not an int, it should throw an exception ERR: Not an integer. What bugs me is, why doesn't it prompt for input again? It just keeps printing the ERR message on screen.

Comment: try adding ``in.nextLine();`` after you print the error message

Answer (score 2):

The nextInt() call does not consume your input (e.g. "abc") if it isn't an integer. So the next time in the loop it still sees the "abc" that you already entered, and that goes on forever. So better use Integer.parseInt(in.next()):

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int k = 0;

    boolean askForInput = true;

    while ( askForInput ) {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        try {
            k = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
            askForInput = false;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("ERR: Not an integer!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that makes sense. But why isn't it printing "Enter an integer" as well? Since that is the beginning of the loop

Comment: @py9 It prints it for me. Double-check your code (if it is saved before compilation/execution) and make sure you are using solution posted here.

Comment: my bad. Works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct form , you should start again the loop :

A you can see i put `System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");` inside **catch**
to make it not reduntant.

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            Scanner in = null;
            int k = 0;

            boolean askForInput = true;

            while ( askForInput ) {

              in = new Scanner(System.in);
              try {
                k = in.nextInt();
                askForInput = false;
              } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("ERR: Not an integer!!");
                askForInput = true;
                System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");

              }
            }
            System.out.print("End");

          }
        }
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of `nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)):

> This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below.
> **If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.**

In other words, `nextInt` leaves the token in the token stream if it is not recognized as a number. One fix might be to use `next()` to discard the token in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the try block, `askForInput` is getting changed to false regardless of the value of `k` ending your loop on the first iteration every time. Try this instead:

```
 while ( askForInput ) {
      System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
      try {
        k = in.nextInt();
        askForInput = false;
      } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("ERR: Not an integer!!");
        askForInput = true; //add this line resetting askForInput to true
      }
    }
```

Comment: but if it changes to false wouldn't it exit the loop then?